# React-native-camera limit barcode scan area

Tags: react-native, camera, qr-code, barcode, react-native-camera

I am using the barcode scanner from [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) and currently if I use it and there are multiple QR-codes closely on top of each other, I point my camera at one and it reads the code above it which is outside of the display on screen but within the cameras view. If however there is no QR-code above the one I want to scan, then it scans the correct one, so it seems like it always scans the top QR-code within the cameras view.

**Here's my question:** Is there a way to limit the "scan area" to be the same size and area as my camera view on my display?

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Camera
    style={styles.preview}
    onBarCodeRead={this.onBarCodeRead}
    ref={cam => this.camera = cam}
    aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>
  </Camera>
  <Button
    style={styles.buttonStyle}
    <Text>{this.state.qrcode}</Text>
  </Button>
</View>

const styles = {
  container: {
    height: 300,
    flex: 1
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }
}
```

Versions, if needed:

```
"react-native": "0.42.3",
"react-native-camera": "0.6.0",
```

Comment: Did you get solution how to disable scanning function in masked area?

Comment: Not a solution, but anyone coming across this issue might want to take a look at another lib which is well maintained and has a working input parameter for reducing the scan area: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera This needs some changes to Java code and the reanimated lib in order to work, so I would not recommend implementing it in a small bugfix ticket

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Since there is no fix yet I would suggest to use another library for barcode mask: https://github.com/shahnawaz/react-native-barcode-mask

You can take a look at it and implement in your project.

**OLD ANSWER**

Now you can limit scan area with `react-native-camera` just make sure to import version `3.19.2` or greater.

```
const CAM_VIEW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('screen').width * 1.5;
const CAM_VIEW_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('screen').width;

const leftMargin = 100;
const topMargin = 50;
const frameWidth = 200;
const frameHeight = 250;

const scanAreaX = leftMargin / CAM_VIEW_HEIGHT;
const scanAreaY = topMargin / CAM_VIEW_WIDTH;
const scanAreaWidth = frameWidth / CAM_VIEW_HEIGHT;
const scanAreaHeight = frameHeight / CAM_VIEW_WIDTH;

class Demo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <RNCamera
                    rectOfInterest={{
                        x: scanAreaX,
                        y: scanAreaY,
                        width: scanAreaWidth,
                        height: scanAreaHeight,
                    }}
                    cameraViewDimensions={{
                        width: CAM_VIEW_WIDTH,
                        height: CAM_VIEW_HEIGHT,
                    }}
                    >
                    <View
                        style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: leftMargin,
                        right: topMargin,
                        width: frameWidth,
                        height: frameHeight,
                        borderWidth: 2,
                        borderColor: 'red',
                        opacity: 0.5,
                        }}
                    />
                </RNCamera>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really know what is happening with me, but it just ain't work. I can see the red rectangle but still it scans the whole screen, is it because I'm using onTextRecognized and not QRcode ?

Comment: @Amor.o I have also noticed that it's scanning the whole screen. Looks like this solution is jut to show the limitation as UI

Comment: @EdisonBiba Indeed, and that's so weird bcz they didn't mention anything in the docs. However, I think that I found a work around, when scanning an object (Text or QRcode) RNCamera will return a block which contains the value + some other details, within those details there is 'origin' which has the x and y of the scanned value. Therefore, I can let it scan the whole screen but I will make an if condition to handle just blocks in my custom area (using the x y values). I know it is a bad practice but it is better than nothing, what do u think ?

Comment: That is a workaround but I don't think that you are winning something there in case of performance because it is already scanning the whole area and it will call your function only in case if finds a qr or a text. The only case where this looks like something to do is when users have to scan QR but there are multiple ones and you want the camera to scan(it will scan those outside the box too) only the one inside the box.

Comment: Still isn't there any solution on this issue?

Comment: Not yet, you can also use this library: https://github.com/shahnawaz/react-native-barcode-mask in order to achieve what you want

Comment: This lib is just provides a visual rectangle, it has no affect to RNCamera and the onBarcodeScanned function whatsoever. Just look at the code: https://github.com/shahnawaz/react-native-barcode-mask/blob/master/index.js

Comment: As for the original answer, why is cam view width 1.5 times the screen width? What is the relation there?

Answer (score 1):

```
import {RNCamera} from 'react-native-camera';
import BarcodeMask from 'react-native-barcode-mask';

const CAM_VIEW_HEIGHT = Dimensions.get('window').height;
const CAM_VIEW_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width;

const left = (Dimensions.get('window').width - 250) / 2;
const top = Dimensions.get('window').height / 2 - 125;

 // this function , in class
 barcodeReceived(e) {
    let coordinat = e.bounds.origin;

    let x_oran = e.bounds.width / CAM_VIEW_WIDTH;
    let y_oran = e.bounds.height / CAM_VIEW_HEIGHT;

    let my_left = left * x_oran;
    let my_left2 = left + 250 * x_oran;
    let my_top = top * y_oran;
    let my_top2 = top + 250 * y_oran;

    if (
      coordinat[3].x < my_left2 &&
      coordinat[3].y < my_top2 &&
      coordinat[2].x > my_left &&
      coordinat[2].y < my_top2 &&
      coordinat[1].x > my_left &&
      coordinat[1].y > my_top &&
      coordinat[0].x < my_left2 &&
      coordinat[0].y > my_top
    ) {
      //ALL DATA in custom area 250*250
      console.log(e);
    }
  
    <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            alignItems: 'center',
            elevation: 2,
          }}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          onBarCodeRead={async e => {
            this.barcodeReceived(e);
          }}
          barCodeTypes={RNCamera.Constants.BarCodeType.qr}>
          <BarcodeMask
            width={250}
            height={250}
            edgeColor="#40BDDE"
            outerMaskOpacity={0.5}
            showAnimatedLine={true}
            animatedLineColor="#40BDDE"
          />
        </RNCamera>
```

Comment: I've tested it and it can scan inside the barcode mask. But to avoid unexpected error, while checking ```coordinat[3].x < my_left2 &&```, I adding ```coordinat.length === 4 && ``` so the out of bound will be handle.

Answer (score 0):

How about do you insert `<View style='your style'/ >` between `<Camera>` and `</Camera>`.

View will be a viewport (focusing on the View tag by Camera)

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   <Camera
    style={styles.preview}
    onBarCodeRead={this.onBarCodeRead}
    ref={cam => this.camera = cam}
    aspect={Camera.constants.Aspect.fill}>

    <View style={'your style'}/>

   </Camera>
   <Button
     style={styles.buttonStyle}
      <Text>{this.state.qrcode}</Text>
   </Button>
</View>
```

const styles = {
  container: {
    height: 300,
    flex: 1
  },
  preview: {
    flex: 1
  },
  buttonStyle: {
    marginTop: 20,
    marginLeft: 20,
    marginRight: 20,
    marginBottom: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also alternatively use [ac-qrcode-rn](http://github.com/MarnoDev/AC-QRCode-RN/blob/master/README.md) which is based upon react-native-camera.It supports both for ios and android and also scans both Qr code and Bar code

Scanning interface can be customized in many ways which helps the scanning UI look great for user. It provides many props through which you can make your own scan area with styles however you like.

Comment: Does that "scan area" restrict scan functions also? It seems you are mentioning about only UI.

Comment: Published 3 years ago, Weekly downloads: 148....